# windows 7 bat file closes after user types response

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

I am trying to write a `bat` file that upon startup will prompt a user.  I can get the user prompt but get an error and the `bat` file closes.  Basically, if the answer is y then a `vb` at the `path` is called and if the answer is n then the `bat` exits. Is the syntax below close?  Thank you :).

```
@ECHO OFF

:choice
set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :L:\NGS\test_email_DOSE.xlsx
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :exit
goto :choice
pause 
exit
```

Comment: Remove `@echo off` to debug!

Comment: I did and the `bat` file closes to fast to read the error.  Thank you :).

Comment: That's what's `pause` for... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:choice
set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?
if /i %c%==y ( 
  L:\NGS\test_email_DOSE.xlsx
) else if /i not %c%==n goto choice
pause
```

In this script the second `if` is only reached when the answer was not 'y'. Also, the `goto` you used always requires a label to jump to. A path is not a label.

I assume of course that `L:\NGS\test_email_DOSE.xlsx` is a valid path.

When I run it on my pc it produces the following (I saved the file as `decide.cmd`):

```
D:\tmp>decide
Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?d
Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?f
Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?y  // (the Excel file is opened)  
Press any key to continue . . .

D:\tmp>
```

Comment: using that I get the prompt but the `bat` closes quickly.  Thank you :).

Comment: Does the script ask you for an input at least?

Comment: I get the user prompt and type "y" then it closes.  Thank you very much :).

Comment: Yes that is a valid path, I can open it through windows explorer.  Thank you :).

Comment: I must have copied something wrong, it works great.  Thank you :).

Comment: I'd not name labels equal to commands, like `choice`; although it works, it is quite confusing when reading the code...

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go this way. The previous answer would do fine. But this approach looks cleaner in my opinion.

```
@ECHO OFF
:choice
SET /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report [Y/N]? 
IF /I %c%==Y (START "" "L:\NGS\test_email_DOSE.xlsx")
IF /I %c%==N GOTO :EOF
GOTO :choice
```